Solving this integral by "u subsitution"
When I was trying to find the area of an ellipse, I come across this integral:
$$S_{ellipse} = 4\frac{b}{a}\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are the semi-major axis and semi-minor axis of the ellipse.
This integral can be evaluate by trig substitution, but I want to find an alternative method using "$u$ substitution", here is my approach:
let $u^2 = a^2 - x^2$, so $x =\sqrt{a^2 - u^2}$, thus:
$$dx = d(\sqrt{a^2-u^2}) = -\frac{u}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}du$$
So the integral now becomes:
$$4\frac{b}{a}\int_{0}^{a}-\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}}du$$
Which is even more complicated than the integral before, so how would I improve my method or are there alternative methods to solve this integral using $u$ subsitution?

Have you considered integration by parts (where one part is 1)? Doing it this way gives you a nice enough integral the second time around, leading to an arctan function.

We write the numerator of the fraction of the subintegral function in the form $-u^2 = a^2 -u^2 - a^2.$
We obtain the difference of the two integrals.
